# Move files from local to network drive without stealing away focus on production computer

Tags: powershell, batch, scheduled-tasks, kiosk

I am looking to move files from local computer to network drive as repeated task once every 24 hours. I have tried couple of things but they all end up stealing away focus on the application as the computer system is on a production floor and will be in use almost 24 hours a day by operators. we cannot afford to lose away the focus and disturb the production software so I am looking for something which can run in invisible/hidden mode type of a thing. I have tried following things but none of them have worked out:

1. Robocopy with batch file using task scheduler - this opens up command prompt for really short duration despite using windowstyle hidden.
2. Robocopy with powershell script automated with task scheduler  - same as above
3. Robocopy with powershell script automated with powershell schedulejob instead of task scheduler
4. Robocopy as start program with task scheduler instead of powershell or batch file.

Additional info:

1. We cannot use vbscript method as vbs are no longer allowed by IT.
2. I cannot select "run even if user is not logged in" in task scheduler as this is a service account in KIOSK mode and we cannot give this service account privilege of "log on as a batch user".
3. I am open to third party softwares as long as they are established company.
4. I am open to code in other scripting language as long as I don't have reinvent the wheel.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a windows service manager.  A windows service can't popup stuff even if it wanted to.

A windows service manager is an application that will run any exe or script as a windows service.  This will include even when a user isn't logged in.

This means robocopy, or batch.. or powershell.. whatever should be on the table.
This means you can isolate the process so even users can't get to it.

There are many that are both commercially and freely available.
**Windows service code I wrote for Windows NT 4 still works flawlessly** so don't worry about the age of the thing you are using.

> The tricky part for you will be figuring out how you are going to
> manage the timeout.  Some support "auto-restart" and give you the
> amount of time you want to pass.  That means your robocopy command
> could simply exit  and will get picked back up after the time passes.

Here are a few: (LOOK THEM UP)

- [srvany.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/create-user-defined-service) OLD but Microsoft and works.
- [nssm](http://nssm.cc/commands)
- [SRVSTART.EXE](https://github.com/rozanski/srvstart)

**The most polished (by far) is pay to play but you said that might be an option**

- [AlwaysUp](https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) .. this one is payed so it also has support.  You could get them to help you configure it and see that it works before you buy it.  Another cool thing about this one as it will even email you the copy logs.. or put them in the windows logs.. or email you if there is a problem.. or make you a ham sandwich.

Keep in mind there are even more out there but I am too lazy to look these things up all night.. hopefully this concept will help you out.

Also be careful.  "windows service manager" can mean a lot of things.  I am talking about an exe that wraps your process and runs it as a service.